# 2 questions. Why isn't my replace function working, and how would I make my variable a different random answer every time?

Tags: python-3.x, random, replace

Here is my code:

```
import random
a=random.randint(0,1)
l=[a,a,a,a,a,a,a]
print(l.replace(',','||||'))
```

I am trying to make a be chosen as 0 or 1 randomly multiple times in the list and I want the numbers in the list to be divided with '||||'. (example: 0||||1||||1||||0||||1||||1||||1) I am bad at programming because I am mostly new to it, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to distinguish between different types in Python. `1` is an integer, `[1, 2, 3]` is a list of integers, `"1"` is a string, and `["1", "2", "3"]` is a list of strings.
2. Lists don't have the `replace` method. Only strings have.
3. the `a` variable is initialized once (with 0 or 1) and then copied several times  into `l`, so all the elements are the same. You want to create several random variables.

If you want to get a string such as `0||||1||||1||||0||||1||||1||||1`, try this:

```
import random

# first create a list of random integers
l = [random.randint(0, 1) for i in range(7)]

# then join these integers converted to strings
s = '||||'.join(str(x) for x in l)

print(s)
```

**UPDATE**: Question from the comment: *As a bonus, how would i add || to the outsides so ||0||||1||||1||||0||||1||||1||||1|| instead of 0||||1||||1||||0||||1||||1||||1?*

You can add those characters to the final string, but now it looks more like you actually want to prepend and append each element with `||x||` and then join them without further delimiters. So choose one of the two alternatives if you know your data. I prefer the second one:

```
s = '||' + '||||'.join(str(x) for x in l) + '||'

s = ''.join(f"||{x}||" for x in l)
```

Comment: As a bonus, how would i add || to the outsides so ||0||||1||||1||||0||||1||||1||||1|| instead of 0||||1||||1||||0||||1||||1||||1?